Error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. React native project on Mac and building with VSC
I am new to coding and this project has been built by bunch of dev's but recently I took it over.
After downloading android studio, and visual studio code and doing everything necessary, I am getting this error, and I am really frustrated.
If even is an expert who can take a look at this and figure the issue, I would really appreciate it!
Macbook 2020 Intel Specs:
Processor: 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 1536 MB
Memory: 16 GB 3733 MHz LPDDR4X
OS: Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Citizens.xcodeproj.
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project Citizens.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme Citizens -destination id=8533909D-2B75-414B-90F9-86B339F30A48
User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
Prepare packages
ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (1 target)
Target 'Citizens' in project 'Citizens' (no dependencies)
GatherProvisioningInputs
CreateBuildDescription
ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.5.sdk -x c -c /dev/null
ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --version --output-format xml1
ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.5.sdk -x c -c /dev/null
ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.5.sdk -x objective-c++ -c /dev/null
ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.5.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null
ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --print-asset-tag-combinations --output-format xml1 /Users/lucius/Desktop/Coding/SourceCode/Citizens-Source-code/Citizens/ios/Citizens/Images.xcassets
ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --version --output-format xml1
ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld -version_details
Build description signature: 23cf7e34eedc7159e42bb44dd464668b
Build description path: /Users/lucius/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Citizens-gxqrbamkjfgdhrfynmjjiuasuarz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/23cf7e34eedc7159e42bb44dd464668b.xcbuilddata
/Users/lucius/Desktop/Coding/SourceCode/Citizens-Source-code/Citizens/ios/Citizens.xcodeproj:1:1: error: Unable to open base configuration reference file '/Users/lucius/Desktop/Coding/SourceCode/Citizens-Source-code/Citizens/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Citizens/Pods-Citizens.debug.xcconfig'. (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-Citizens/Pods-Citizens-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-Citizens/Pods-Citizens-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Citizens/Pods-Citizens-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Citizens/Pods-Citizens-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Citizens/Pods-Citizens-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Citizens/Pods-Citizens-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Citizens' from project 'Citizens')
** BUILD FAILED **
lucius@Josephs-MacBook-Pro Citizens %
I downloaded everything needed to run this project. Please see below. I have been trying to connect the SDK and it won't connect on visual studio code, and even when I select the emulator, it doesn't save it.
Common
✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode
Android
✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Versions found: N/A
Version supported: 33.0.0
✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

iOS
✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
✓ Ruby - Required for installing iOS dependencies
✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
✓ ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
✓ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment
Errors:   2
Warnings: 0
